# Execute second python script only when the first script is done

Tags: python, lua, subprocess, python-os

I execute python script from browser via lua script:

```
os.execute('python scriptname.py --arg1 Test --arg2 Test2')
```

and I do it again (e.g. by refreshing the page, sending the form)

```
os.execute('python scriptname.py --arg1 Test3 --arg2 Test4')
```

I would like the second script to be executed only when the first script is done to the end.
I would like the scripts to be added to the queue and executed from the oldest script to the newest.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar question to a discussion thread that I am part of for Lua in *Codea* (Lua development environment for the iPad): See [here](https://codea.io/talk/discussion/9239/implement-blocking-http-request#latest). On that page, follow *se24vad*’s use of a thread queue. Note that code on that page is not necessarily portable, since Codea provides some functionality not built in to Lua. I point to this page for the ideas, not for the specific code.

Basically, the idea is that you need to queue up the functions in a thread queue (i.e. Lua coroutines). In his particular implementation you do not move on to a new coroutine until the one at the top (index 1 in the queue table) is complete. In other words, the coroutine calls are blocking.

You will want to implement a coroutine queue, with each of your `os.execute` calls as a separate coroutine.

Now, how that fits in to the rest of your code, I am not sure. I do not know what code you have that controls when your page refresh happens. You would need some sort of controller code to keep track of the coroutine queue.

If a thread queue isn’t possible in your use-case, then maybe the python scripts need to somehow report completion back to the browser. When a new execute call is made, it checks the completion variable first before proceeding.